# how to include my homepage and scc in to a plugin

Tags: plugins, urls, directory

```
<?php    
    Plugin Name: Contact Form
    Plugin URl: https:/jeti.com/
    Description: my first plugin aplication contact form
    Version: 1.0
    Author: Admin
    Author URL: https://www.jeti.com
    License: GPL2
    
    */
    add_action('init', 'registerPlugin');
    
    function registratePlugin(){
    
    register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'myPluginCallBack');
    
    get_home_path('home.php');
    
    }
    
    function myPluginCallBack (){
    
    ?>
    <script> alert('plugin activate');</script>activate
    ]
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you're trying to do?  What does home.php do?  Where does it get used?

Comment: homepage.php in my front page of contact form when i fill aplying datas